# How does the SpringApplication.run() method work?

Tags: java, spring

I'm working on redeveloping Java microservices as AWS serverless functions, and the project I chose as the basis for this is built using Spring Boot. I've been trying to draw a class diagram for the application to work out what I need to replace with the call for the lambda function, but I don't understand what the application's flow is after the class calling the Spring Boot application passes itself as an argument to the SpringApplication.run() method.

Here is the link to the repository and some sample code https://github.com/paulc4/microservices-demo

```
public class AccountsServer {

    @Autowired
    protected AccountRepository accountRepository;

    protected Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(AccountsServer.class.getName());

    /**
     * Run the application using Spring Boot and an embedded servlet engine.
     * 
     * @param args Program arguments - ignored.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Default to registration server on localhost
        if (System.getProperty(RegistrationServer.REGISTRATION_SERVER_HOSTNAME) == null)
            System.setProperty(RegistrationServer.REGISTRATION_SERVER_HOSTNAME, "localhost");

        // Tell server to look for accounts-server.properties or
        // accounts-server.yml
        System.setProperty("spring.config.name", "accounts-server");

        SpringApplication.run(AccountsServer.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi & Welcome! :-) There you go: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/main/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication.java#L1289 (it's open source!;)

Comment: ..but as "user", of course it is good to have [spring reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/) and [spring-boot reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/) "under the pillow".